# Should I add more colors?

Tags: forms, gui-design, metro, flat-design

I'm developing an UI for my application and since we're in 2015 a lot of people really like flat/minimal UIs. Take a look at the screenshot of my UI and tell me if I should change it, I think there's too much black color, only 3 base colors and 1 situational color when something is clicked, is this enough to make a good modern flat UI?

[image]

Comment: Your question appear to me mostly opinion based – it sounds a bit like "Do you like my design?".  Please try to be a bit more specific and ask about some aspect you really want to know.

Comment: "Colors" are very subjective, so I'd suggest to focus on contrast. For example you'd need a lighter shade for "disabled" if that's a possibility. The icons don't appear to be "black" but dark gray - you could lighten all of them slightly if you think it's too dark now. Do you need to differentiate the "selected" tab & its contents more clearly? BTW, I'm not sure why you've used A-Z/Z-A ( "sort ascending/descending" in several applications) for Import/Export. Otherwise the icons make sense ... What's the tiny "eject"/dropdown button for? Hardly even noticed that at first.

Answer (score 1):

I think its great. You should only add new colors when the new colors signify a different meaning of something.

Also having too many colors can confuse users because they may be overloaded with trying to figure out why the color is different and does that signify a different/hidden meaning to the feature.

A fair amount of users are color blind adding new colors does nothing for them. For this reason i prefer to alter shades of the same color light blue dark blue etc.

Consider the feeling and perception that certain colors have in certain cultures.

Be aware that different parts of the world feel differently about certain colors.

Come typical american perceptions of colors can be found in this article on [Color and User experience](http://interactions.acm.org/blog/view/color-and-user-experience)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your project is okay considering general UI rules. Base and accent colors are okay too, but if you want more than a primitive windows shell, you need to know more about Design Language definition.

If you use design language, all elements in your interface, such as button, font and colors will represent the unique part of whole general conception.

For now you have only few black images, and default text size. You can redesign your app using "material design" from Google, or create your own. :)

http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html